# When running a bind server where do I specify my lan machines hostnames?

Tags: linux, dns, lan, arch-linux, bind

I'm running an arch linux bind server, and trying to accomplish a pseudo local development domain called ld.pvt so that from my other machines I have web accessible access to the web servers on the bind machine.

Where im getting confused is where do i map my LAN machines?  i.e. all the other ones, the dev machine, the printer, etc..  is that what bind is ever for, or should they just go in /etc/hosts?

**/etc/hosts**

```
#<ip-address>   <hostname.domain.org>   <hostname>
127.0.0.1       falcon.ld.pvt           falcon          localhost

#ipv6 support
::1             falcon.ld.pvt           localhost

#localhost.localdomain
192.168.1.99    redtail.ld.pvt          redtail
192.168.1.150   osprey.pd.pvt           osprey
192.168.1.254   router.pd.pvt           router          gateway
```

**zone file**

```
$ cat /var/named/ld.pvt.zone
$TTL 7200
; ld.pvt
@               IN      SOA     falcon.ld.pvt. postmaster.ld.pvt. (
                                        200701171       ; Serial
                                        3H              ; Refresh
                                        15M             ; Retry
                                        1W              ; Expire - 1 week
                                        1D )            ; Minimum

                IN      NS      falcon.ld.pvt.
                IN      MX      10      mail.ld.pvt
falcon          IN      A       192.168.1.10
redtail         IN      A       192.168.1.99

imap            IN      CNAME   falcon
smtp            IN      CNAME   falcon
mail            IN      CNAME   falcon
www             IN      CNAME   falcon

;*wildcard is bad because you then cant use multiple hosts since oyou wildcarded everything in bulk to falcon alone, for e.g.
;*.ld.pvt       IN      CNAME   falcon
; *             IN      CNAME   falcon
```

**named.conf**

```
$ cat /etc/named.conf
// vim:set ts=4 sw=4 et:

acl "local" {
        127.0.0.0/8;
};

acl "wolfnet" {
        192.168.1.0/24;
};

acl "trusted" {
        "local";
        "wolfnet";
};

acl "forwarders" {
        8.8.4.4;
        8.8.8.8;
};

options {
    directory "/var/named";
    pid-file "/run/named/named.pid";
    dnssec-validation auto;
    listen-on-v6 { any; };
    listen-on { "trusted"; };

    interface-interval 101;

    allow-recursion { "trusted"; };
    recursion yes;
    allow-query { trusted; };
    allow-transfer { none; };
    allow-update { none; };

    forward only;
    forwarders { "forwarders"; };

    query-source address * port 53;
    transfer-source address * port 53;
    notify-source address * port 53;
    query-source-v6 address * port 53;
    version none;
    hostname none;
    server-id none;
};

logging {
    channel default_file {
        file "/var/log/named/default.log" versions 3 size 5m;
        severity dynamic;
        print-time yes;
    };
    channel general_file {
        file "/var/log/named/general.log" versions 3 size 5m;
        severity dynamic;
        print-time yes;
    };
    channel database_file {
        file "/var/log/named/database.log" versions 3 size 5m;
        severity dynamic;
        print-time yes;
    };
    channel security_file {
        file "/var/log/named/security.log" versions 3 size 5m;
        severity dynamic;
        print-time yes;
    };
    channel config_file {
        file "/var/log/named/config.log" versions 3 size 5m;
        severity dynamic;
        print-time yes;
    };
    channel resolver_file {
        file "/var/log/named/resolver.log" versions 3 size 5m;
        severity dynamic;
        print-time yes;
    };
    channel xfer-in_file {
        file "/var/log/named/xfer-in.log" versions 3 size 5m;
        severity dynamic;
        print-time yes;
    };
    channel xfer-out_file {
        file "/var/log/named/xfer-out.log" versions 3 size 5m;
        severity dynamic;
        print-time yes;
    };
    channel notify_file {
        file "/var/log/named/notify.log" versions 3 size 5m;
        severity dynamic;
        print-time yes;
    };
    channel client_file {
        file "/var/log/named/client.log" versions 3 size 5m;
        severity dynamic;
        print-time yes;
    };
    channel unmatched_file {
        file "/var/log/named/unmatched.log" versions 3 size 5m;
        severity dynamic;
        print-time yes;
    };
    channel queries_file {
        file "/var/log/named/queries.log" versions 3 size 5m;
        severity dynamic;
        print-time yes;
    };
    channel network_file {
        file "/var/log/named/network.log" versions 3 size 5m;
        severity dynamic;
        print-time yes;
    };
    channel update_file {
        file "/var/log/named/update.log" versions 3 size 5m;
        severity dynamic;
        print-time yes;
    };
    channel dispatch_file {
        file "/var/log/named/dispatch.log" versions 3 size 5m;
        severity dynamic;
        print-time yes;
    };
    channel dnssec_file {
        file "/var/log/named/dnssec.log" versions 3 size 5m;
        severity dynamic;
        print-time yes;
    };
    channel lame-servers_file {
        file "/var/log/named/lame-servers.log" versions 3 size 5m;
        severity dynamic;
        print-time yes;
    };
    category default { default_file; };
    category general { general_file; };
    category database { database_file; };
    category security { security_file; };
    category config { config_file; };
    category resolver { resolver_file; };
    category xfer-in { xfer-in_file; };
    category xfer-out { xfer-out_file; };
    category notify { notify_file; };
    category client { client_file; };
    category unmatched { unmatched_file; };
    category queries { queries_file; };
    category network { network_file; };
    category update { update_file; };
    category dispatch { dispatch_file; };
    category dnssec { dnssec_file; };
    category lame-servers { lame-servers_file; };
};

zone "ld.pvt" IN {
        type master;
        file "ld.pvt.zone";
        allow-update { none; };
        notify no;
};

view "trusted" {
    match-clients { trusted; };
    zone "ld.pvt" {
        type master;
        file "ld.pvt.zone";
    };
};

zone "1.168.192.in-addr.arpa" IN {
    type master;
    file "1.168.192..zone";
    allow-update { none; };
};
```

**Iptables**

```
$ iptables --list
Chain INPUT (policy DROP)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate INVALID
ACCEPT     icmp --  anywhere             anywhere             icmp echo-request ctstate NEW
UDP        udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate NEW
TCP        tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp flags:FIN,SYN,RST,ACK/SYN ctstate NEW
REJECT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
REJECT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             reject-with tcp-reset
REJECT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             reject-with icmp-proto-unreachable

Chain FORWARD (policy DROP)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain IN_SSH (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere             recent: CHECK seconds: 10 hit_count: 3 TTL-Match name: sshbf side: source mask: 255.255.255.255
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere             recent: CHECK seconds: 1800 hit_count: 4 TTL-Match name: sshbf side: source mask: 255.255.255.255
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             recent: SET name: sshbf side: source mask: 255.255.255.255

Chain TCP (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
DROP       tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:http STRING match  "GET /w00tw00t.at.ISC.SANS." ALGO name bm TO 65535
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:22
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:http
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:https
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpts:hbci:cgms
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:35729
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:mysql
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:27017
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:953
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:netbios-ssn
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:microsoft-ds
IN_SSH     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:22

Chain UDP (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:27017
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:domain
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp dpts:netbios-ns:netbios-dgm
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:microsoft-ds
```

From a dev machine on the lan, routing through the gateway of .254 always show this, no access: 
[image]

**Edit:**

also, note I think I have a huge problem, I opened port 953, not 53, which should I switch?

Comment: So where should i be defining the gateway(and or router), and redtail, osprey, and all other lan machines at??? (only in ONE place preferably)

note, redtail, and other lan boxes have their gateway pointed to the gateway, and the gateway dns server are 192.168.1.10 (falcon) and 8.8.4.4(google), and alternatively i have also tried putting those same entries in the dns servers for the manual windows config for teh lan machine, for e.g. redtail, I 192.168.1.99, S 255.255.255.0, G 192.168.1.254, D 192.168.1.10, but i think the former is cleaner, and should work by letting router do it.

Comment: to clarify what i was talking about, the former uses the router to find the dns addresses, and the latter directly has them also typed in the ip configuration of the nic.

Comment: Let's try to limit this SuperUser.com question to one major topic at a time.  If a client machine receives configuration details that specify which IPv4 address to use as a DNS server, that is done with another protocol (typically DHCP), and is unrelated to the configuration of BIND which is the "DNS server" software.  "Gateway" refers to routing, which is yet another technology unrelated to BIND.  If you have questions about these other protocols, please ask about them in separate questions.  (Otherwise the answers will probably crossover and that is prone to cause substantial confusion.)

Comment: @toogam ok can you point out the exact excerpts where i go off track and ill better undstand how to edit.  thanks.  then we can delete these little comments...

Comment: "have their gateway pointed to" sounds like routing.  Unrelated to BIND.  "gateway dns server" = unclear.  Gateway is routing, DNS is name resolution.  Think of them as separate services.  "letting router"...  this is bringing "routing" into a conversation about DNS configuration.  Your  next comment sounds like automatic address configurations (DHCP).  You're probably best off setting up just one of these things at a time, and troubleshooting just one of these things at a time.

Comment: If you're looking for direction to simplify things, I suggest you temporarily forget about BIND/internal DNS server.  Just use an external DNS server like 8.8.8.8, and make sure that routing (everything can ping everything by IP address) and DHCP (addresses/configurations get assigned automatically) are working fine.  Then, after those things work, you can set up BIND, and troubleshoot by using "nslookup ebay.com 192.0.2.4" (or whatever your BIND server's address is).  Adjusting DHCP to point to the internal DNS server can be a last step, easy to do when all everything else works.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/33303/discussion-between-toogam-and-brian-thomas).

Answer (score 1):

The individual machines get defined in the zone file.  At the moment I'm writing this answer, zone file appears to have been posted incorrectly.  However, from the fragments I can see, the machine named "falcon" appropriately has an A record that points to 192.168.1.10

That's done perfectly.  redtail is also defined.  Also, "imap" and "smtp" (and others) are CNAMEs that point to falcon.  That's all done correctly.  Simply add similar lines for osprey and gateway.  Or, if you want to do things like the hosts file, you can set up the name "router" to have an A record, and have the name "gateway" be a CNAME that points to "router".

Since the names, like "falcon", don't end with a period, those names are being treated as partial names.  The rest of the domain (ld.pvt, mentioned earlier in the file) will get added to the end of the partial names.  (If you don't want that, add a period.  Periods, at the end of the names, can make a big difference.)

Comment: note, falcon, is the master server for everything, files, hostnames, dns, web files, etc... other boxes will be win machines connecting in.  the only static i have so far is redtail, osprey isnt static, well the printer is, `192.168.1.20`.  Also i dont use mail services yet, just readying because i will.

Comment: thats the correct zone file, i believe.  what do you see thats throwing you off, the rule set for logging?  or ..  AHHHHHHHHH hang on.

Comment: @BrianThomas It is perfectly acceptable (and common) to have one device perform multiple roles, like a name resolution (DNS) server, an automatic address assignment (DHCP) server, and routing (being a gateway).  However, you really should keep in mind that each of those roles can also be run on separate machines, which very little interaction.  Even if the services are on the same machine, think of them as separate services, or else your questions will likely be more confusing (and you may have more trouble keeping these things straight yourself).

Comment: Checking this setup now, ill let you know how it goes.  and wow is that how the dots work?  then `ld.pvt.` is correct then, and `falcon`(no dot) in the A record if i want `falcon.ld.pvt` then right?  ok confused, should i have falcon.ld.pvt (without the dot) in the SOA also?

Comment: I guess that depends if i want services, i do, e.g. othersite.falcon.ld.pvt.  am i on right track?  note, i think what im looking for is mainly `falcon.ld.pvt`(as opposed to just `falcon`) to be accessible, more than `redtail.ld.pvt` ( i may never need it that was), since i will always be developing from redtail, so no need to have access to redtail.ld.pvt since nothing hosted on there. suggestions for my zone A records then?

Comment: shoudl i put all my configt files updates in my OP?    i have a feeling it will render this post useless, i think ill put them in a pastey instead
HERE IS MY LATEST: hosts http://pastebin.com/sMCwLgv4  named conf : http://pastebin.com/gVHRTAp1 and Zone file here  http://pastebin.com/sD2zzkwj

Comment: i was testing the 1D entries, not sure what they are for other than overriding cache maybe?

Comment: I mean i cant even ping google.com from a ternimal in falcon now, i cant ping `falcon.ld.pvt` from redtail, or `printer`(might not be answering), but i can ping `falcon` from redtail

Comment: please note, before i accept this answer, i need to see it working, and i have lost ALL DNS with this configuration.

Comment: @BrianThomas: I'm currently planning to end my involvement w/ help on this question. You've added comments a dozen times.  As I understand, lengthy conversations are contrary to Stack Exchange guidelines, so I used the automatically-provided suggestion to make a chat room. You didn't participate. I think nobody else answered yet because you scared them off, by asking a bunch of questions about many different topics, and added text to the official question (by asking yet another question). The format of this Q&A site is meant to be: each created "question" contains just one specific question.

Comment: sure, that must be where i am going wrong, thanks for your help thus far.  i didn't notice any chat room.  ill try to see how i can break up the questions, and i had noticed this.  i will piece the out and ask them individually.  If anybody gets it, feel free to say what i am obviously doing wrong to get any kind of DNS at all.  The problem has been consistent along ALL the edits for the most part, so someone will probably see what im doing wrong in my examples above. Thanks.